# Update git submodule branch on remote server

Tags: git, push, git-submodules

I accidently got detached head in my git submodule, when I edited the code inside of it and pushed. So now the remote branch is broken and won't build. So I resetted the submodule to the master, but only locally. What I need to do now is to "push" it somehow to the remote repository. But git doesn't show any changes to commit or anything to push.